# Convert string into array by space

Tags: php, arrays

I have below sample string

```
device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274
```

I want to convert this string into array

Expected output

```
device_name="Text Data"
d_id=7454579598
status="Active" 
Key=947-4378-43248274
```

I tried this using explode function for this but its gives below output

```
$data='device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274';
$arr= explode("",$data);
```

generated output

```
device_name="Text 
Data"
d_id=7454579598
status="Active" 
Key=947-4378-43248274
```

Comment: explode function will convert your data into array.

Comment: Yes but there is one problem.Using that, it also explode value.

Comment: you need like $array['device_name']... ?

Comment: @JawlonRodriguez Yes

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions. They are actually fun :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
    $str = 'device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274';
$pattern = '/(\\w+)\s*=\\s*("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'\\s>]*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$attrs = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (($match[2][0] == '"' || $match[2][0] == "'") && $match[2][0] == $match[2][strlen($match[2])-1]) {
        $match[2] = substr($match[2], 1, -1);
    }
    $name = strtolower($match[1]);
    $value = html_entity_decode($match[2]);
    $attrs[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($attrs);
```

output

```
Array ( [device_name] => Text Data [d_id] => 7454579598 [status] => Active [key] => 947-4378-43248274 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this small and trivial example using a regular expression:

```
<?php    
$subject = 'device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274';
$pattern = '/^device_name="(.*)" d_id=(\d+) status="(.*)" Key=([0-9-]*)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens);
```

This creates this output:

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(77) "device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274"
  [1] =>
  string(9) "Text Data"
  [2] =>
  string(10) "7454579598"
  [3] =>
  string(6) "Active"
  [4] =>
  string(17) "947-4378-43248274"
}
```

From here you probably can go on yourself :-)

Comment: How to do it dynamically ?This is just sample data.

Comment: OK, you did not mention this in your question. I assumed you have a fixed format you want to process. For dynamic matching the pattern obviously becomes more complex. Take a look at the answer @Karan posted above. Looks good to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert into JSON. [JSON Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$str = 'device_name="Text Data" d_id=7454579598 status="Active" Key=947-4378-43248274';
$json = '{'.str_replace('=',':',$str).'}';
$json = '{'.str_replace(' ',',',$str).'}';
```

get as JSON. like:

```
{device_name:"Text Data",d_id:7454579598,status:"Active",Key:947-4378-43248274}
```

and convert into array

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

and output

```
array(4) {
    ["device_name"] => "Text Data"
    ["d_id"] => 7454579598
    ["status"] => "Active"
    ["Key"] => "947-4378-43248274"
}
```